# Is there a way to bind a unknown JSON to a JsonObject in AspNetCore?

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, dynamic, binding

I am trying to bind a dynamic `json` input to a `JsonObject` in AspNetCore, but it is not working

> ("The JSON value could not be converted to
> System.Collections.IEnumerable. Path: $ | LineNumber: 1 |
> BytePositionInLine: 11.").

Where am I doing wrong?

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult RetrieveData([FromBody] JsonObject request)
{ 
  //stuff
}
```

Are there any other ways to bind a generic Json?

Answer (score 0):

As the error message said, `JsonObject` require an json that contains list `KeyValuePair` or `Dictionay<string, JsonValue>`, please see this link
[JsonObject Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.json.jsonobject?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1)

for convert unknown json maybe you should use somethine like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult RetrieveData([FromBody] object request)
{ 
//try to cast object
var castedObject=(YourObject)request;

}
```